# How do I compile gcc 5 for my Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: software-compilation, gcc

I have a Raspberry Pi 2. What is the best way to get a functional gcc 5 (from the current trunk) on the Raspberry Pi?

Since compiling gcc takes a good two hours on my x86-based computer and probably a lot longer on a Raspberry Pi, it would be great if someone, who already tried this or has more experience with compiling gcc than me, could either:

- Confirm if it's possible to compile gcc on the Raspberry Pi itself (is there enough memory?), or;
- Give me a tested set of configuration options to cross-compile gcc 5 for the Raspberry Pi.

### What this question is not about

Yes, you can cross-compile software from your x86 box for the Raspberry Pi. No, I'm not interested in answers that explain to me how to build a cross-compiler, except if that instruction is immediately followed by instructions on how to cross-compile a gcc5 that will run on the Raspberry Pi and compile for the Raspberry Pi with that cross-compiler. Answers that do not answer the question will be downvoted.

Comment: Closed as defunct ;)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this works, but, I am trying the build instructions I found here: [How to Build a GCC Cross-Compiler for the Raspberry Pi](http://blog.felipe.rs/2015/01/20/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler-for-the-raspberrypi/).

Edit: It worked to build 4.9.2. I will also try to build 5 with it.

Comment: I do not want to build a cross compiler. I want to build a gcc5 that runs on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What do you plan to compile it with? I used the cross compiler to build GCC that runs on the Pi.

Comment: That's what I'm asking you. Ideally, I would compile it on the Pi itself but this is probably not possible. I have a cross compiler for the Pi, but as I mentioned before, setting up an environment to cross-compile gcc is tricky and I don't know how to do that. What I want is a gcc5 that runs on the Pi. If you can tell me how to get that, your answer is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

> Confirm if it's possible to compile gcc on the Raspberry Pi itself (is there enough memory?)

Yes, it's possible to compile on a Raspberry Pi. However

1. in some cases it might take tremendously longer than you have patience for
2. it **will** uselessly burn out precious flash cells and the SD card **will** prematurely wear out.

Iif GCC5 is not available on any Linux distribution that you want to install it with, then the only *viable* option is to cross-compile for the Raspberry Pi.

> Give me a tested set of configuration options to cross-compile gcc 5 for the Raspberry Pi.

Now talking of my personal experience: whenever I **need** to cross-compile, I resort to Gentoo Linux, with its versatile `crossdev` tool-chain. It'll take quite some time for the tool chain to set up but you only have to do this once.

Any time you need to cross-compile a package requires a simple `armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi-emerge -av <package>` on the Gentoo cross-compiling host.

Follow [Gentoo Embedded Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Embedded_Handbook) for more detailed information on how to setup your cross-compiler.

You did not tell but if you have a Debian-based distribution on your Pi you will also have to [package](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial) the compiled product for Debian. You don't need to install a full-fledged Gentoo with a graphical desktop. You can install Gentoo in a chroot and use it to cross-compile whenever you need to. More on that if you want.

Comment: I have a cross-compiler that runs on my main machine and compiles for the Raspberry Pi. How do I cross-compile a gcc 5 with it so it runs on the Raspberry Pi? Note that burning out flash is a non-issue, the file systems are mounted from NFS to avoid that. Yes, I want to compile software on the Raspberry Pi. That's the whole point.

Comment: @FUZxxl how can we answer that if 1) you don't explain what your cross-compiling toolchain is and 2) what your target distribution is? Have you also double-checked GCG-5 is really not available for the distribution on your Pi? We don't guess, we need clues.

Comment: Back when I made this post, I used a Debian both on the Pi and on my main machine. Right now I have a Debian on the Pi and a FreeBSD on my main machine. The cross-compile toolchain is gcc based. However, if you could just walk me through the steps to cross compile a gcc, that would be super helpful, because that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Please indicate in your question, with links if possible, what steps/tutorial/instructions you followed to get your cross-compiling toolchain ready. Every cross-compiling tool chain has its own lot of peculiarities and specifics. Also bear in mind FreeBSD is not LInux.

Comment: I installed the toolchain that came with Debian and the one that came with FreeBSD.

Comment: I have rejected your edit because it restricts the question to only a part of what I want.

Comment: Then I'm sorry but I don't understand what you want exactly.

Comment: My goal is to have a gcc5 that runs on the Raspberry Pi that compiles binaries that run on the Raspberry Pi. I want to know how to reach that goal. Other things (like making a cross-compiler) are not the topic of this question unless they help reaching the goal.